# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt in python3.7

Tags: python

when i run python3.7 in pycharm(matplotlib error)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

then i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PyCharm 2017.2.3/Workplace/SimpleGA-master/ga.py", line 3, in 
  <module>
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

and i tried to find matplotlib in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib,but not find python3.7 package

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the matplotlib modules.
 + pip install matplotlib

Then try again.

Thanks!

Comment: where is python3.7 64bit's download link